# Parquet-MR library is throwing an exception while reading (FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY / UUID) column

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

I have a parquet file which has a column "FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY / UUID", when I feed  it to parquet-mr library, I get this exception:

> Exception - caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: The requested schema is not compatible with the file schema. incompatible types: required binary
>
> Identity (STRING) != required fixed_len_byte_array(16) Identity (UUID)
>
> at org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory$ColumnIOCreatorVisitor.incompatibleSchema(ColumnIOFactory.java:101)
> at org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory$ColumnIOCreatorVisitor.visit(ColumnIOFactory.java:93)
> at org.apache.parquet.schema.PrimitiveType.accept(PrimitiveType.java:602)
> at org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory$ColumnIOCreatorVisitor.visitChildren(ColumnIOFactory.java:83)
> at org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory$ColumnIOCreatorVisitor.visit(ColumnIOFactory.java:57)
> at org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType.accept(MessageType.java:55)
> at org.apache.parquet.io.ColumnIOFactory.getColumnIO(ColumnIOFactory.java:162)
> at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:135)
> ***

Btw,

1. I am using latest parquet-mr library i.e. 1.12.0
2. When i feed same file to parquet cpp library, it is able to decode it. So, I  just want find out, is there any known issue in parquet-mr library w.r.t UUID?

-DevD

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your code